# How to create a progressbar capturing the progress of a subprocess in tkinter with threading

Tags: multithreading, tkinter, progress-bar, parameter-passing, python-3.6

I am currently programming a GUI with tkinter in Python 3.6 for another Program, which is called through subprocess. I would like to represent the progress of the Program called, with a Progressbar, popping up in another window as soon as I hit the 'Run Program' Button. The value of the progressbar is set by arguments passed from the subprocess script, where I calculate the percentage of progress in a function. What I need:
1. How do I properly use the Threading-Module for spawning the subprocess?
2. How do I import a function (and therefore its arguments) of a script, that runs with command line parameters?
I was looking for a answer in other posts the whole day, but couldn't really connect them to my problem.

I tried to spawn the subprocess by simply calling its function with `threading.Thread(target=self.runProgram()).start()` 
Apparently the GUI-program still waits until the subprocess/Thread is finished and then continues with creating the progressbar, but I expected it to happen at the same time. I then tried to import the percentage value of the subprocess-Program, which didn't work due to missing parameters. Also I don't think that this would really work the way I want it to, because I want the arguments passed during the runtime, when the subprocess is called. It's very hard to properly explain what I am looking for, so here is some code:

GUI-Program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory,askopenfilename
import os,subprocess
import threading

class eodApplication(tk.Tk):


   def __init__(self):

#different entryboxes are created, not necessary for understanding 
          self.runButton=''
          self.progress=''
          self.window = tk.Tk()
          self.window.geometry("500x350")
          self.window.configure(background="white")
          self.window.title("End of Day Application")
          self.create_widgets()



   def create_widgets(self): 

  #creating entryboxes initiated in __init__-method, containing paths one can browse for and a submit/'Run Program'-Button
          self.submit()     


   def submit(self):
 #Button calls function when pressed
          self.runButton=ttk.Button(self.window,text='Run Program',command=lambda:self.bar_init())
          self.runButton.grid(row=7, columnspan=2)

    def bar_init(self):
        barWindow = tk.Tk()
        barWindow.geometry("250x150")
        barWindow.configure(background="white")
        barWindow.title("Progress")
        self.progress=ttk.Progressbar(barWindow, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate",value=0)
        self.progress.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        threading.Thread(target=self.runProgram()).start()
        from PythonProgrammeDWH import get_percentage
        self.progress["value"] = percentage


    def runProgram(self):
        devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        subprocess.call(f"{self.entryboxPyExe.get()} {self.entryboxPyCode.get()} {self.entrybox64.get()} {self.entrybox66.get()} {self.entryboxXsd.get()} {self.entryboxOutput.get()} {self.entryboxXmlExe.get()}",cwd=os.getcwd(),stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,shell=True)
eodApplication=eodApplication()
eodApplication.window.mainloop()
```

PythonProgrammeDWH (subprocess):

```
def main(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3],sys.argv[4]):
  ~ a lot of stuff going on ~
      sumFiles=len(os.listdir(path))
      checkedFiles=0
      for file in os.listdir(path):
            checkedFiles+=1
            get_percentage(sumFiles, checkedFiles)
def get_percentage(sumFiles, checkedFiles):
      percentage= round((checkedFiles/sumFiles)*100)
      return percentage
#percentage is the argument I want to pass to the other script for updating the progressbar
```

Comment: `thread` could use `queue` to send information to main thread with GUI and GUI could use function which get it and update progressbar and it use `tk.after()` to runs itself after few milliseconds.

Comment: tkinter example which use thread with queue and after() to update data in label but you can use progresbar. https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/thread-queue/main%20.py